# Strict Standards: Non-static method MAD_Admin_Redirect::redirect() should not be called statically in ad/index.php on line 13

Tags: php

I have used madserve and I have installed it but I get this error:

> Strict Standards: Non-static method MAD_Admin_Redirect::redirect() should not be called statically in /home3/******/public_html/ad/index.php on line 13

What I can do?

**index.php**

```
<?php
    define('ROOT_INDEX', true);
    // Require the initialisation file
    require_once 'init.php';

    // Required files
    require_once MAD_PATH . '/functions/adminredirect.php';

    // Redirect to the admin interface
    if (MAD_INSTALLATION_STATUS == MAD_INSTALLATION_STATUS_INSTALLED)
    {
        MAD_Admin_Redirect::redirect();
    }

?>
```

**/functions/adminredirect.php**

```
<?php
    class MAD_Admin_Redirect
    {

        function redirect($adminPage = 'www/cp/index.php')
        {
            header ("Location: ".$adminPage."");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Note that you should add `exit;` after the call of `header()`, because the rest of your script will still be executed after this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mark `MAD_Admin_Redirect::redirect` as static

```
<?php
class MAD_Admin_Redirect
{

    public static function redirect($adminPage = 'www/cp/index.php')
    {
        header ("Location: ".$adminPage."");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, disable strict error reporting or make the method static

```
<?php

class MAD_Admin_Redirect
{
    public static function redirect($adminPage = 'www/cp/index.php')
    {
        header ("Location: ".$adminPage."");
    }
}
```